# Testfor command not working with radius

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a redstone signal out of a command block when a player is in the radius of 3, so I made a commandblock with the text: `testfor @a[r=3]`.

A redstone clock is bound to it, and gives it a new one every second.
Now for some reason when I am in the radius, it won't give a signal. Can anyone help?
I'm playing Minecraft 1.6.1 without any mods

Comment: Are you using a Comparator to receive the signal from command block, or just redstone wire? If you are alone within 3 meters, the signal will be of only strength 1, are you sure you do not miss it?

Answer (score 2):

Had just the same problem but did some testing on it! it seems that the old stupid north south east west bug still apply to this! I simply switched sides that I had my comparator hooked up to and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

First, you need 2 hoppers facing each other. Place any item in the hopper. The item should be going back and forth between the hoppers. Now grab a redstone comparator. Stand on top of any hopper and place the comparator outwards. The two redstone torches on the comparator should blink while the bottom one should not light up. Now grab a command block. Type in: `testfor @p[r=6]` Now place another comparator while standing on top of the command block facing a block with a redstone torch on one side. The redstone torch should turn off. Now run redstone wire to yet another redstone torch on another block. Connect the torch to an iron door. Then the door will open when a player gets close!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use @p instead of @a, ( /testfor @p[r=3] )

Comment: This only means that ONLY the closest player to the command block in the radius will be detected.

Comment: @RavenM Which wouldn't make a difference, because the closest player to the command block will still be detected, and if the closest player isn't the one within the radius then there can't be any player within the radius.

Answer (score -1):

Try a slower redstone clock. You may be lagging.